# how to show only images without showing videos when choose photo button is tapped in iPhone app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

In my app a choose photo button is there,when tapped on the button it should take to iPhone photos and show only images without showing videos present.With my code its showing images as well as videos.What could be the way to show only images.looking for help,thanks in advanace.Below is my code:

```
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>
-(void)choosePhotoFromExistingImages
{
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])
{
    controller = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    controller.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    controller.allowsEditing = NO;
    controller.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    controller.delegate = self;
    [self.navigationController presentViewController: controller animated: YES completion: nil];
}
```

}

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
if (picker==controller){
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion: nil];
    UIImage *image1 = [info valueForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    CGFloat compression = 0.9f;
    CGFloat maxCompression = 0.1f;
    int maxFileSize = 250*1024;

   NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image1, compression);

    while ([imageData length] > maxFileSize && compression > maxCompression)
    {
        compression -= 0.1;
        imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image1, compression);
    }
    imgVwProfile.image=image1;

    // get the ref url
    NSURL *refURL = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];

    // define the block to call when we get the asset based on the url (below)
    ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *imageAsset)
    {
       // ALAssetRepresentation *imageRep = [imageAsset defaultRepresentation];
     // strProileImg=[imageRep filename];
        ALAssetRepresentation *imageRep=[imageAsset defaultRepresentation];
       strProfileImg = [imageRep filename];
        NSLog(@"%@",strProfileImg);

    };


    // get the asset library and fetch the asset based on the ref url (pass in block above)
    ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [assetslibrary assetForURL:refURL resultBlock:resultblock failureBlock:nil];
}


}
```

Comment: on replacing with controller.mediaTypes = @[kUTTypeImage]; getting an error use of undeclared identifier kUTTypeImage

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the [mediaTypes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/mediaTypes) property:

```
controller.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage, nil];
```

**Reference:**

> **mediaTypes**
>
> An array indicating the media types to be accessed by the media picker
>   controller.
>
> `@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *mediaTypes`
>
> **Discussion**
>
> Depending on the media types you assign to this property, the picker
>   displays a dedicated interface for still images or movies, or a
>   selection control that lets the user choose the picker interface.
>   Before setting this property, check which media types are available by
>   calling the `availableMediaTypesForSourceType:` class method.
>
> If you set this property to an empty array, or to an array in which
>   none of the media types is available for the current source, the
>   system throws an exception.
>
> When capturing media, the value of this property determines the camera
>   interface to display. When browsing saved media, this property
>   determines the types of media presented in the interface.
>
> By default, this property is set to the single value `kUTTypeImage`,
>   which designates the still camera interface when capturing media, and
>   specifies that only still images should be displayed in the media
>   picker when browsing saved media. To designate the movie capture
>   interface, or to indicate that only movies should be displayed when
>   browsing saved media, use the `kUTTypeMovie` identifier in a statement
>   like this:
>
> `myImagePickerController.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];`
>
> To designate all available media types for a source, use a statement
>   like this:
>
> `myImagePickerController.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];`

Comment: am getting an error use of undeclared identifier kUTTypeImage

Comment: @user2552751: Import `#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>` and add mobilecoreservice framework

Comment: For Xamarin.iOS: just do not provide media types option and it will work, because by default it picks image only.

Answer (score 4):

## Swift 4

```
// Make sure you need to import MobileCoreServices
import MobileCoreServices

pickerView.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum
pickerView.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String]
```

Answer (score 3):

By default, mediatypes array property is set to the single value kUTTypeImage, which designates the still camera interface when capturing media, and specifies that only still images should be displayed in the media picker when browsing saved media.

**swift 3**:

```
    import MobileCoreServices
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String] // this is the default value. 
    // you don't have to set it.
```

To designate all available media types for a source, use a statement like this:

```
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .photoLibrary)!
```

NB: import ***MobileCoreServices*** if you need to set the media types.

Answer (score 1):

try to replace your line setting the mediaTypes by:

```
controller.mediaTypes = @[kUTTypeImage];
```

Comment: am getting an error use of undeclared identifier kUTTypeImage

Answer (score 1):

In Swift:

```
imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
  #import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
   controller.mediaTypes =[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *)    kUTTypeImage, nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3.0, **by default you will be shown images only, not videos. So, no need to implement anything.** But if you want to see all types of media present in photo library, use following code:

```
let pick = UIImagePickerController()
pick.mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .photoLibrary)!
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
controller.mediaTypes = @[kUTTypeImage];
```

Comment: am getting an error use of undeclared identifier kUTTypeImage